# How to use HttpRequestInterceptor in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, http, interceptor

I would like to get request body, so I decided to implements HttpResponseInterceptor interface. How to do it properly?

```
public class CustomHttpInterceptor implements org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptorHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {

    }
}
```

Should I create CustomHttpInterceptor as a bean? How to add it too be visible for Spring?

Comment: You don't. Either use a `HandlerIncterceptor` if you want to log incoming requests. If it is for `RestTemplate` use a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and register it with the template.

Comment: I can't log/use incoming request body using HandlerInterceptor, cause i have an exception: "getReader() has already been called for this request."

Comment: You can only do that with a filter, for which spring already has an implementation.

Comment: Yes, You have right, thanks. It works! I used custom wrapper and set filter order to HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the spring's provided `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` implement the interface and add a Config class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` which has a method

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new LoggerInterceptor());
}
```

You can find more details on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: But i want to read requestBody and when i Use Spring interceptor it is not possible.